# .htaccess mass redirection from "page ?w=number" to another one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect from a page to another with parameters with htaccess

`example.com/?w='some generated numbers'`
to
`example.com` ?

`'some generated numbers'` is randomly generated numbers or titles.
I've tried something like this:

```
"RewriteRule ^?w=(.*) index.php"
```

but get an 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the apache rewriting module clearly states that you cannot capture the query string of a requested URL by means of a `RewriteRule`:

> REQUEST_URI:
> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

You need to use a `RewriteCond` instead to be able to access that `%{QUERY_STRING}`. That is what is also shown in all examples about that here on SO or elsewhere on the internet.

This might point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)w=[^&]+(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSD,R,L]
```

The documentation of the apache rewrite module is, as typical for OpenSource software, of *excellent* quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "RewriteRule ^?w=(.*) index.php"
> ```

This would have resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error since it is syntactically invalid (and the regex would fail to compile). So, I can't see how this would result in a "400 error" - which is an error associated with the *request*.

However, you can't match the query string part of the URL with the `RewriteRule` directive. The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only. To match the query string you need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, to redirect from `example.com/?w=<random-string>` to `example.com/` you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^w=
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R,L]
```

The `QSD` flag is necessary to discard the original query string from the request.